# Can't hide UIMenuController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to disable the menu controller for a UItextField. I have used the following code to try to disable the controller menu

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{
    return NO;
}
```

But it didn't work, I always get the menu (copy, paste, cut) when selecting the text in the UITextField.
I don't know what is the source of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you place these code?

you should make a subclass of `UITextField` and override

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
```

in it, just as your code.

Comment: I have put it into view controller, as per your answer this is the reason why it didn't work, right?